# Some text in tables not visible

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I am unable to see some of the text entered into a table unless 'show all non-printing characters' is on.  At the same time, some text in the table is visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated that toggling 'show all non-printing characters' displays some of your text. Text is typically not non-printing characters so it sounds like something askew with the formating marks.

Click the Office button and then click Word Options.

Click Display

Under "Always Show These Formatting Marks On the Screen", fiddle with the check boxes.

Comment: It's not the formatting marks that are the problem. It's text that isn't visible.

Comment: changed it a bit to further explain my thinking here.

Comment: Thanks but no go yet.  I am using a Mac so have checked my settings: Word/Preferences/View.  For non-printing characters I had already checked the All box.  It is pretty wonky, I agree.